# How do I track the location/state basis the mobile number?

Tags: mobile, tracking

I am trying to identify the location/state of 100 Indian Mobile numbers. Could someone help me? Are there any online tools available to upload the excel and get the location?

Answer (score 0):

Telephone calls do not have hard requirements for the source number to be in the header of the call packets and can be either forcefully omitted or edited. There’s no sure-fire way of being able to reliably get location information as a result.